# Prove that the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$ with the Euclidean metric is closed

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-verification

> I want to show that the $x$-axis is closed.

Below is my attempt - I would appreciate any tips on to improve my proof or corrections:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with the usual metric.
Want to Show: $\{(x,y) | x ∈ \Bbb R, y = 0\}$ is closed

Claim: $\{(x,y) | x ∈ \Bbb R, y ≠ 0\}$ is open

Proof: Let $\{(x,y) | x ∈ \Bbb R, y ≠ 0\} = C$. 
Let $z$ be an arbitrary $(a,b) ∈ C$ and let $$ε = \min\{d(z,(0,y)), d(z,(x,0))\}.$$
Then for any $p ∈ $B_ε$(z)$, $B(p) ∈ \{(x,y) | x ∈ \Bbb R, y ≠ 0\}$ with radius $ε/2$.

Comment: instead of $\min\{d(z,(0,y)),d(z,(x,0))\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}$ you can just use $\min\{|a|,|b|\}$. But note that this way you show that the union of the $x$- and the $y$-axis is closed. So take $ε=|b|$ to show this only for the $x$-axis.

Comment: I wouldn't write "Let (X,d) be a metric space with the usual metric."  That doesn't make sense.  You might write "Let (X,d) be the Cartesian plane with the usual metric." or "Let $(X,d)$ be $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual metric.  And of course you could mention that that's a metric space. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of $\epsilon$ has problems: what are $x$ and $y$? They’ve not been defined up to this point, so $\epsilon$ isn’t defined. The only specific coordinates that are available at this point for you to work with are $a$ and $b$ (and specific real numbers like $0$).

HINT: If $z=\langle a,b\rangle\in C$, try letting $\epsilon=|b|$.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! Why would ϵ be defined as |b| and not as min(|a|,|b|)?

Comment: @user2853043: You’re welcome! Because you don’t care how far $z$ is from the $y$-axis; you care only how far it is from the $x$-axis. And as Stefan H said, it might be **on** the $y$-axis, in which case $a=0$, which is not a usable $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Another fun way you might approach this problem is to let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x,y) = y^2$. If you know/can show that $f$ is continuous, then it will imply that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can as well show that the interior of $R$ is empty in the standard topology. Since any open ball around every point of $R$ contains points in $R$ and outside $R$ then the boundary of $R$ is $R$. By definition, closure of is the union of $R$ and its boundary. Therefore Closure of $R$ is just $R$.

Please criticize this proof so I can make corrections if any.